# Constraints in codechef

Tags: c, loops, multidimensional-array, constraints, runtime

I am solving this problem currently: https://www.codechef.com/problems/DISHLIFE

The input format in this question is as follows (all integers):

3(n) 4(k)

3 1 2 3

2 1 3

2 1 2

In the 2nd to 4th line, the 1st number denotes the number of elements in the line. Let us denote this number by p

It is clearly mentioned in constraints that 1<=p<=k.

I want to take

1 2 3

1 3

1 2

as a 2-D array. So, I declare this array by a[n][k]. But when I do this, I get wrong answer or runtime error in some test cases. When I take a[n][1000], my code works totally fine.

Here is the editorial for the question: https://discuss.codechef.com/questions/95658/dishlife-editorial?page=1#130775
 As explained in the editorial, I am taking a 2-D array a[n][k] It's size is n * k because the number of columns is Pi and Pi<=K. Please read the constraints and input section of the code: codechef.com/problems/DISHLIFE But, when I submit the problem I get runtime error and wrong answer in 2 out of 8 test cases.Instead of a[n][k], when I declare a[n][1000], my code gets accepted. I just want to know why a[n][k] gives a runtime error as the number of columns in the matrix will never be greater that k

Here is my code (if anyone is interested):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    long t,n,k,i,j,s,all,some,sad;
    scanf("%ld",&t);
    while(t--){
        long temp;
        sad=all=some=0;
        scanf("%ld%ld",&n,&k);
        int a[k+1],matrix[n][k],size[n];
        for(i=1;i<=k;i++)
        a[i]=0;
        for(i=0;i<n;i++){
            scanf("%ld",&s);
            size[i]=s;
            for(j=0;j<s;j++){
            scanf("%ld",&matrix[i][j]);
            temp=matrix[i][j];
            a[temp]++;
        }
        }
        for(i=1;i<=k;i++)
        if(!a[i])
        sad=1;
        if(sad==1){
            printf("sad\n");
            continue;
        }

        for(i=0;i<n;i++){
            for(j=0;j<size[i];j++){
            temp=matrix[i][j];
            if(a[temp]==1){
            all++;
            break;
            }
        }
        }
        if(all==n)
        printf("all\n");
        else
        printf("some\n");

}

}
```

Also, I saw a code in which even a[n][20] ran totally fine. Here is that code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int t,n,k,i,j,a[100000],b[100000][20],ch;
    scanf("%d",&t);
    while(t--)
    {
        scanf("%d%d",&n,&k);
        for(i=0;i<k;i++)
        a[i]=0;
        ch=0;
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            scanf("%d",&b[i][0]);
            for(j=1;j<=b[i][0];j++)
            {
                scanf("%d",&b[i][j]);
                a[b[i][j]-1]++;
            }
        }
        for(i=0;i<k;i++)
        if(a[i]==0)
        {
            ch=1;break;//impossible
        }
        if(ch==1)
        printf("sad\n");
        else//possible
        {
            for(i=0;i<n;i++)
            {
                ch=0;
                for(j=1;j<=b[i][0];j++)
              {
                if(a[b[i][j]-1]==1)//its contri matters
                {
                    ch=1;break;
                }
              }
            if(ch==0)//its contri doesn't matter
            {
                printf("some\n");
                break;
            }
            }
            if(ch==1)
            printf("all\n");
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Guide me what I am missing

Comment: You are missing most of the information to explain what your problem is. What does not work? What happens unintentionally? Where are you stuck? What is your guess? "I am trying code chef, here is my code, it does not work" is not a question.

Comment: @Yunnosch I didn't ask anything like that. I have explained everything before writing the code.
Okay let me elaborate. 
Here is the editorial for the question: https://discuss.codechef.com/questions/95658/dishlife-editorial?page=1#130775

As explained in the editorial, I am taking a 2-D array a[n][k] It's size is n * k because the number of columns is Pi and Pi<=K. Please read the constraints and input section of the code:  https://www.codechef.com/problems/DISHLIFE
But, when I submit the problem I get runtime error and wrong answer in 2 out of 8 test cases.

Comment: @Yunnosch Instead of a[n][k], when I declare a[n][1000], my code gets accepted. I just want to know why a[n][k] gives a runtime error as the number of columns in the matrix will never be greater that k

Comment: Would you like to [edit] your question for giving helpful additional explanations? In the comments that information is less helpful.

Comment: @Yunnosch Done. Can you help now?

Comment: You defined `matrix` with `k` columns, but in `for(j=0;j<s;j++)` loop you treat it as if it has `s` columns.

Comment: @WeatherVane That's because the matrix isn't completely filled. I am taking MAXIMUM no. of possible columns(in the declaration part) so that no problem will occur